# how to know an android app view's hierarchy ,except hierarchyviewer

Tags: android, performance, analysis, hierarchyviewer

Use android/sdk/tools/hierarchyviewer.bat can help us know the hierarchy view of an android application, but when the hierarchyviewer maybe crash when the app is crashed or some other reasons. So I want to know is there any other way I can get an app view's hierarchy,  especial the Parent Child Relationships?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know layered structure of your app's UI, try : https://github.com/JakeWharton/scalpel

It is a surgical debugging tool to uncover the layers under your app.

This might help you untangle relationships that you need.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I want to know the layer even the app not show on the screen

Comment: Why is this a constraint : not show on the screen ?

Comment: because I change the android sdk's code, the app will not measure\layout\draw on the screen successful